# Where is my flaw with the calculation of this cdf?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

I want to calculate the ratio distribution $X/Y$ of two continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$ with each having support $(0, \infty)$

I was starting like that:

$$\mathbb P\left(\frac{X}{Y}\leq z\right)=\int_{0}^\infty f_Y(y) F_{X\mid Y}(zy \mid y)dy$$

Now:

$$F_{X\mid Y}(zy \mid y)=\int_{0}^{zy} \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}dx   =\frac{\frac{dF_{X,Y}(zy,y)}{dy}}{f_Y(y)}$$

and hence:

$$\mathbb P\left(\frac{X}{Y}\leq z\right)=\int_{0}^\infty \frac{dF_{X,Y}(zy,y)}{dy}dy=\left[F(zy,y)\right]_0^\infty=1,$$

which of course is not correct. Anyone can see my mistake? Thank you very much in advance

Comment: I do not understand the second equality of the second line.

Comment: Then  maybe there is my flaw... :-) The idea is that $\frac{d}{dy}F(x,y)=\frac{d}{dy}\int_0^y \int_0^x    f(x,y)dx dy=  \int_0^x  f(x,y)dx$ but here it seems wrong....

Comment: But I do not have a joint pdf but only a joint cdf and the pdf of $X$ and $Y$... Any idea how to get past that?

Answer (score 2):

Putting together your first equation and the first equality in the second, you are esentially getting

$$ p=P( X/Y \le z)= \int_0^\infty \int_0^u f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dx \, dy, \hspace{1cm} u=u(y)=zy \tag{1}$$

which is right, of course (there was no need to use a conditional for that, though).

Your problem in what follows is that you are mixing total derivatives with partial derivatives.

When we write (in general) the formula

$$ \frac{d F_{X,Y}(x,y)}{dy } = \int_{-\infty}^x f_{X,Y}(x',y) dx' \tag{2}$$
we are implicity assuming that the derivative is done by varying $y$ and keeping $x$ constant, i.e., it's actually a partial derivative. When the variables have some arbitrary functional dependence, we should be more careful and write that partial derivative explicitly:

$$ \frac{\partial F_{X,Y}(u,v)}{\partial v } = \int_{-\infty}^u f_{X,Y}(u',v) \, du' \tag{3}$$

In our case, plugging $(3)$ into $(1)$ we get

$$p= \int_0^\infty \frac{\partial F_{X,Y}(u,y)}{\partial y }  dy \tag{4} $$

with $u=u(y)=zy $. Now, the integrand is not a total derivative, hence you cannot apply the fundamental theorem of calculus directly. The relation is

$$ \frac{d F_{X,Y}(u,y)}{d y } = \frac{\partial F_{X,Y}(u,y)}{\partial u } \frac{du}{dy}+
\frac{\partial F_{X,Y}(u,y)}{\partial y } = \frac{\partial F_{X,Y}(u,y)}{\partial u } z +
\frac{\partial F_{X,Y}(u,y)}{\partial y } \tag{5}$$

You could isolate from this equation the integral in $(4)$ and replace it there... but you will get something similar (probably not simpler) than $(1)$.

Comment: Okay thank you very much, I think I understand my mistake now. So if I have given $F(x,y)=\exp(-\frac{1}{\max(x,y)})$ and I want to calculate the ratio distribution I first say $F(zy,y)=\exp(-\frac{1}{y\max(z,1)})$. So if $z\geq 1$ the probability $p$ is equal to: $p =\int_0^\infty \exp(-\frac{1}{zy})(zy)^{-2}z-\exp(-\frac{1}{zy})(zy)^{-2}z dy=0$ and for $z<1$ we have that the derivative with respect to $u$ is zero and hence it reduces to $p= \int_0^\infty \exp(-\frac{1}{y})(y)^{-2} dy=1$, right? In other words? if $\max(zy,y)=zy$ we treat the cdf function like a constant and

Comment: hence the derivative with respect to $y$ is zero and hence our probability is zero and in case $\max(zy,y)=y$ we just calculate the derivative with respect to $y$, right?

Comment: mmm unless I'm confused,  if $F(x,y)=\exp(-\frac{1}{\max(x,y)})$ then the joint density is zero everywhere, except on the (non derivable) region $x=y$ , i.e., we have a degenerate joint density when $X=Y$ - and hence the problem is trivial (but should not be attacked by this approach)...

Comment: Okay, maybe I need to be more precise; If the joint cdf is given by $F(x,y)=\exp(-\frac{1}{\max(x,y})$, then the joint cdf is only determined by the bigger of the two values. We would get such a joint cdf e.g. if we have a random variable $R$ and $X:=R$ and $Y:=R$; Then the ratio would be a constant (namely 1) and hence it really does not make sense to consider it like that; What I actually have $F(x,y)=\exp(-(f(x)+g(y)+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{a_k \max(x,y}))$; Then we could see it like that: We have random variables $R_1,...,R_t$ and subsets

Comment: $R_X \subseteq \{R_1,...,R_t\}$ and $R_Y \subseteq \{R_1,...,R_t\}$ and $X=\max\limits_{i \in R_X}c_{xi}R_i$ and $Y=\max\limits_{i \in R_Y}c_{yi}R_i$ and then we could divide the two sets $R_X$ and $R_Y$ in random variables that are only used to define $X$, random varialbes that are only used to define $Y$ and random variables that used for both, in $X$ and $Y$ and we would end up e.g. with such a joint cdf